# Table of Eratosthenes' sieve

Tags: nicematrix

The code below produces the following output where the elements in the last column are incorrectly placed. Is this easy to fix?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\eratosthenes{ m }{   
    $\AutoNiceMatrix[hvlines, columns-width=auto]{#1-#1}{\cellval{#1}{\arabic{iRow}}{\arabic{jCol}}}$
}

\NewDocumentCommand\cellval{ mmm }{    
    \int_eval:n{#3 + #1*(#2 - 1)}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\eratosthenes{10}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. If I copy your code into a new document and compile, the alignment looks just right (using PDFLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with TexLive 2021 or 2022 on Overleaf)

Comment: @JasperHabicht How do you compile and which version of nicematrix do you have? I can reproduce the issue with and up-to-date texlive2023

Comment: This looks like a bug. I send a message to the author.

Comment: Even if changing to a fixed with, the last column always seems to be one colsep smaller than the ones before

Comment: In texlive2022 (overleaf)  it seems to work fine. Seems to be a new bug

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz The Log says "nicematrix 2022/05/25 v6.9". This is probably not the newest version.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Indeed, current version is `2023/06/04 v6.20`

Comment: Fun fact: with fully-updated texlive2021, the cells are shifted to the other site :) Maybe one should take the average of multiple versions and things will be fine :)

Comment: Yes. That seems to be a bug in a recent version of `nicematrix`. I will investigate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That bug has been corrected in the latest version of `nicematrix` (v. 6.20a 2023-06-30).